# STM32 wakeup from CAN bus

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, interrupt, can-bus

I am trying to wake up the CPU from the CAN bus but it fails. Data from the bus processor receive but does not wake it up, for example, an interrupt from GPIO wakes it up and then it responds to the last 3 data from CAN Bus

CPU STM32F103C6

```
  HAL_SuspendTick();
  HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&htim1);
  HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode(PWR_MAINREGULATOR_ON, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim1);
  HAL_ResumeTick();
  tick_sleep = HAL_GetTick();
```

[HAL Config interrupt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P6sj.png)

CAN Bus config

```
    void MX_CAN_Init(void)
{
 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 0 */
 
  /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 0 */
 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 1 */
 
  /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 1 */
  hcan.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan.Init.Prescaler = 6;
  hcan.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_2TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoBusOff = ENABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoWakeUp = ENABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoRetransmission = ENABLE;
  hcan.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 2 */
  HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan);
    CAN_FilterTypeDef  sFilterConfig;
    sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh   = 0xFFFF;
    sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow   = 0xFFFF;
    sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0;
    sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0;
    sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;
    sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 0;
    sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
    sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_16BIT;
    sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
    sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 0;
 
    HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan,&sFilterConfig);
  /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 2 */
 
}
```

Comment: Ok I find solution. I forgot add
HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING);

Comment: You could post an answer to your own question showing the fix. That's perfectly fine & encouraged - in case others with the same problem comes across this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**I forgot to run interrupts from CAN**

```
      /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_CAN_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim1);
  HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING); // CAN interrupts start
```